# lie vs fabricate. When to use which one in what situation?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, connotation, register

I'm having hard time distinguishing between these words and come to ask you gracious people for help.

I recently learned the word "fabricate". I got into the dictionary for more details, and found as follows.

According to Cambridge Dictionary

> ***Fabricate***
> to invent or produce something false in order to deceive someone:

At first glance, I thought the word "lie" (in verb form).

However, in google, I could not able to find useful comparison between those words, like 'which  context are they used differently?' or 'what vibe are they used in diverse situations?'. And I think the reason why I can't find comparison in google is that they are used in very different situation.

What word to choose in what situation?

Comment: Hint: it's possible to lie without inventing any details.

Comment: It's a good idea to look at dictionaries which **provide sample sentences** taken from real sources. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/fabricate) (formerly Oxford Dictionaries) and [Word Hippo](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/sentences-with-the-word/fabricate.html) are especially useful. Remember to also type in the past tense of new words i.e. fabricated, too

Comment: Are you aware of the critical differences in underlying tone, register, and appropriateness that always result from selecting Germanic words like *lie* or *speak falsely* versus selecting Latinate words like *fabricate, dissemble,* or *prevaricate*? You cannot begin to understand when and why natives choose one term over the other until and unless you fully internalize this key concept about the lexis of the language.

Comment: If you only recently learned this word I think you should be posting on English Language Learners, whether or not English is your native tongue. Please reread the sentence regarding the scope of this site in the [Tour]

Comment: I can't find an explicit reference, but as a native speaker it seems that "lie" (either a verb or a noun) has some connection with the act of *speaking*, but "fabricate" does not. For example you can *fabricate* a false document (e.g. a fake passport) ,but you can't "lie" a it. The Latin or French etymology of "fabricate" relates to *making* something, not *saying* something.

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that to accuse someone of lying is in many circles considered socially unacceptable: it shows a lack of respect, and is banned in the British House of Commons. So people become creative with euphemisms for lying to avoid making a direct accusation.

Comment: It's worth noting that _fabricate_ also means to make something (for example, in a previous job, we contracted with a machine shop to create custom robot frames for us - they were _fabricating_ the frames).  If you ask me what color the sky is and I say "yellow", I'm lying.  But if you ask me what I did last night and I create a non-trivial (and non-true) story about what I did, I'm both lying and telling you a _fabrication_.  However, I don't think I've ever used the verb _to fabricate_ as a straight up synonym for  the verb _to lie_

Comment: Fabricating lies is more involved than just telling them. Feel the Latin. :)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As a commenter suggested, when we use *fabricate* in the context of deception,<sup>1</sup> we imply that some effort went into inventing or producing something disingenuous, either a story or an artifact, like a fake document. If you simply said 'no' when you knew full well that the truth demanded 'yes', it is unlikely anyone would say that you 'fabricated' an answer. But everyone would agree that you lied.

<sup><sup>1</sup>In other contexts, *fabricate* can mean simply to *invent, create,* or to *construct, manufacture; specifically, to construct from diverse and usually standardized parts* [(*Merriam-Webster*)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fabricate).</sup>

On a formal grammatical side, *fabricate* is a transitive verb, while *lie* is most commonly intransitive.<sup>2</sup> Normally, we simply say that e.g. *he lied,* or else we add a preposition phrase and say that *he lied **about** [something].* In contrast, we say that *he fabricated **[something]***, as in *he fabricated a story.*

<sup><sup>2</sup>Much more rarely, *lie* can also function as a transitive verb. Here is an example from [*Merriam-Webster*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lie): *He lied his way out of trouble.*</sup>

As far as the meaning, *fabricate* means 'To concoct in order to deceive' (***fabricated** a convincing excuse)* [*(American Heritage)*](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=fabricate); 'To "make up"; to frame or invent (a legend, lie, etc.); to forge (a document)' (*Numerous lies, **fabricated** by the priests..were already in circulation*; *If any person..wilfully **fabricate** in whole or in part,..any voting paper.*) (OED).

As for *lie* and similar words, [*Merriam-Webster*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lie) has the following useful discussion:

> ***lie, prevaricate, equivocate, palter, fib*** mean to tell an untruth. ***lie*** is the blunt term, imputing dishonesty. // *lied
> about where he had been* // ***prevaricate*** softens the bluntness of
> *lie* by implying quibbling or confusing the issue. // *during the hearings the witness did his best to prevaricate* // ***equivocate***
> implies using words having more than one sense so as to seem to say
> one thing but intend another. // *equivocated endlessly in an attempt
> to mislead her inquisitors* // ***palter*** implies making unreliable
> statements of fact or intention or insincere promises. // *a swindler
> paltering with his investors* // ***fib*** applies to a telling of a
> trivial untruth. // *fibbed about the price of the new suit* //

Comment: Thanks for the plentiful additional information on top of the great answer, appreciate you!

Comment: Non-European learners have little feel for what happens when choosing words from the Germanic part of the lexis versus those from the Romance part. It won't jump out at them and color everything the way it will for a native, since they aren't attuned to those origins. So they will pick words that don't match what natives would for a given case.

Comment: Re: "He lied his way out of trouble": Interesting example! I'll have to think about this a bit more, but I think I'd be more inclined to say that even intransitive verbs license the "[...] one's way [...]" frame. (Note that even with transitive verbs, the semantic roles of, say, the "her" in "he charmed her" and the "his way" in "he charmed his way into her heart" are completely different.)

Comment: I would add that in practice, it appears more common to call a lie a "prevarication" than it is to substitute the verb form of lie with "prevaricate."

Answer (score 15):

To fabricate originally was to make, and this is still one of the meanings. One can fabricate a story, a piece of cloth, or a car. To fabricate a story is to make it up, and the fabricated story is false because the truth does not need to be made up. To fabricate evidence is to make it (instead of discovering it.
See https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/fabricate

To lie is to tell a false statement intending it to be taken as the truth. If you tell your fabricated story as the truth then you have lied. If you present your fabricated evidence as real evidence you have also lied, and your research will be suspect even if your results are actually true.

To call a statement a fabrication is to say it was made up, and is therefore a lie instead of being the truth. These days the word is more often used in this sense than with the earlier meaning.

Comment: In Italian the word  *fabrica* means *factory*, a building where workers make / manufacture goods. This seems to be the key to the difference between  *lie* and *fabricate*, the latter requires greater effort and thought.

Comment: "the word is more often used in this sense" seems unlikely, but then I do both metalwork and sewing as hobbies, so maybe hear the making-from-stock sense more often than most people. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22fabricate%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2007,cd_max:2019&lr=lang_en has only one use of the 'lie' meaning in the first page

Comment: Technically, to lie is to tell a statement one _believes to be_ false intending it to be taken as the truth.  [It's possible to lie, and yet be telling the truth, if one tells a statement, which one believes to be false, intending it to be taken as the truth, when said statement, unbeknownst to one, _actually is_ true.](https://www.egscomics.com/?date=2003-06-27)

Comment: @Vicki Quite correct. Even a complex lie may, by accident, turn out to be the truth.

Comment: Indeed, and "fabricating evidence" may be creating something to persuade people of the truth of something that is in fact true: my grandmother fabricated a birth certificate to prove she was born in Argentina, which is in fact where she was born.

Comment: One can also fabricate tangible goods, such as mechanical [parts](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22fabricate+parts%22).

Answer (score 0):

To lie means to deliberately deceive by telling something that you know or at least believe to be false in the sense of *not true*. You tell something that you think is not real.

If you fabricate something, then it will be false in the sense of not being *authentic* – but it doesn't mean you necessarily think it's *untrue*. In fact, I reckon most people who *fabricate* something do it to support something they believe to be *true*, but can't prove honestly, so they make up something that they think represents the truth. This is then still *deceit*, but not a *lie*.

Of course you can also fabricate to support a lie, but this is not implied by the word.

Answer (score 0):

**Prevaricate** is the word you want. It essentially means to lie but it’s nicer in, say, political debates than to say someone is a liar or mendacious.